# Onblur does not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**The Scenario:**

I would like to fire the function `checkDOMChange` (*which hides `ul` tags that are empty*)
once an `input` is filled and unfocussed but currently, the function is not being called. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcbcq1jz/5/).

```
function checkDOMChange() {
  if ($("div[id$='DoIQualify_financials'] div").hasClass("field-invalid")) {
    if ($('.borrower1Salary_errors li').length == 0) {
      jQuery("ul.borrower1Salary_errors").hide();
    }
    if ($('.borrower2Salary_errors li').length == 0){
      jQuery("ul.borrower2Salary_errors").hide();
    }
  }
```

Comment: There is typo error `function checkDOMChange() {` not closing well. check the console

Comment: You have a scope issue as well.

Comment: See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/vcbcq1jz/10/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your script to be defined when the script is being parsed, at runtime there is no `field-invalid` class because the DOM is empty (no HTML elements have been loaded yet).

To do this, assign the function to a variable, shown below.

```
checkDOMChange = function (){
       if ($("div[id$='DoIQualify_financials'] div").hasClass("field-invalid")) {
           if ($('.borrower1Salary_errors li').length == 0) {
               jQuery("ul.borrower1Salary_errors").hide();
           }
           if ($('.borrower2Salary_errors li').length == 0) {
               jQuery("ul.borrower2Salary_errors").hide();
           }
       }
   }
```

This way, the function is invoked after the DOM has loaded the required elements. There's a great explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) which explains the difference in more detail.

You could also choose to put your function in a `window.onload` event which waits until the DOM has loaded before executing scripts.

A third option would be to put your script just before the closing `body` tag of your HTML (browsers read HTML top-down so it will load the DOM before reading the `script` tag).

You also need to close your first `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

```
   function checkDOMChange() {
       if ($("div[id$='DoIQualify_financials'] div").hasClass("field-invalid")) {
           if ($('.borrower1Salary_errors li').length == 0) {
               jQuery("ul.borrower1Salary_errors").hide();
           }
           if ($('.borrower2Salary_errors li').length == 0) {
               jQuery("ul.borrower2Salary_errors").hide();
           }
       }
   }
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $(document).on('blur', '.inputbox', checkDOMChange);
   }
```

This is what you want, I Guess